# Create html link based on selected option

Tags: jquery, html, parameters, hyperlink

I have a menu with different links to `jsp's`. i am sending parameters to the `jsp's` in the `url`

```
<li><a href="<%=GlobalData.HOME_JSP%>?p=history">History</a></li>
```

i also have a `select` where user can select a device

```
<select id="device_select" >
<option value='a'>a</option>
<option value='b'>b</option>
</select>
```

Now i am trying to send another parameter to the jsp like this

```
<li><a href="<%=GlobalData.HOME_JSP%>?p=history&d=">History</a></li>
```

The new parameter `d` should have the current value selected in the select box

I can do this by simply binding a click event on the `li` and then create the link using simple jquery script (as i can get the selected value in jquery).

is their any way to write the script inside the `a` tag ? -- something like :

```
<li><a href="<%=GlobalData.HOME_JSP%>?p=history&d=getSelectedValueUsingSomeFunction()">History</a></li>
```

Comment: you will need to distinguish the values of your `<option>`s... how do you intend to do that? As shown, your code doesn't!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do:

```
<a onclick="$(this).attr('href', '<%=GlobalData.HOME_JSP%>?p=' + $('#device_select').val());"></a>
```

I've written this by heart and not tested yet.